# Alexa Skill Flow Builder Linux Availablity

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, voice

Where can I find Linux distribution of Alexa Skill Flow Builder?

Documentation says requirements for Alexa Skill Flow Builder include Linux.

However, I do not see a download link for Linux Distributions.

Where can I find Linux distribution of Alexa Skill Flow Builder?

Documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/use-the-skill-flow-builder-editor.html

I visited the Alexa SKill Builder Documentation

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFwAz.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no Linux version of the Skill Flow Builder. The documentation link https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/use-the-skill-flow-builder-editor.html at the moment also do not say a linux version exist. If it was there before, it could have been a mistake. You can probably try to see if you can get it running via an emulator on linux.